# bootmgr missing no disc. please help noobie here!

Tags: boot

I was running ubuntu dual boot and wanted to remove windows altogether. Ubuntu was installed on my pc not on disc. I then used os uninstaller to get rid of windows. Ubuntu is still in there somwhere, but after reboot i just get bootmgr missing message.  I have no windows disc at hand till monday and only my phone for internet.  Any way around this at all? Please help. System is mainly asus, i think. I know there is an ezflash option that appears at reboot... Lost here lol :-)
maya

Comment: try `boot-repair` tool

Comment: Sorry real newbie here how can i get it going? No boot at all, i have only bios options and my mobile for net.  Might be just daft newbie, have no clue lol thanks for commenting :-)

Comment: You will need ubuntu live disk. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Ok so stuck with no computer till monday lol. Serves me right for being rash :-) really hate windows tho lol

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any boot CD You will not be able to repair Your MBR :( It is not possible from BIOS setup.

Here is described how to restore Grub from Ubuntu CD:

[How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

You can also fix this using other Linux/Unix boot CD's. Even from Windows (installed) or DOS (Grub2Dos).

Comment: It is also possible with a liveUSB. Use the media which you used to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  Just walked 8 miles to get my copy of windoze so i can sort it all out... Will now be able to run ubuntu on a disc and make sure i have all my bases covered before i scrub windows again. Shudda done that the first time lol. Thanks for the help :-)